# Folder Redirection GPO fails with 502 "Can't create folder" error for folders that already exist

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10, folder-redirection

For a very long time now, we have relied on a registry setting to handle folder redirection for our Documents folders. Part of the login script sets `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Personal` to use `\\fileserver\%username%`. We have other scripts that automatically create and share those folders with working permissions at the same time user accounts are created.

This *works*, but I know it's not the typical way to handle this. Especially with Windows 10, the semi-annual feature updates have occasionally broken the process. Therefore I'd like to start using the built-in (and supported) Folder Redirection GPOs.

My test policy is setup with these options:

```
Basic - Redirect everyone to the same location
Redirect to the user's home direction
Grant the user exclusive rights: UNCHECKED
Move the contents of Documents: UNCHECKED
Also apply redirection to Windows 2000 etc: CHECKED, but we have no systems like this
Leave the folder in the new location when the policy is removed
```

I have a test account with the old registry change removed from the login script. For other details, I'm testing from a Windows 10x64 1909 Enterprise computer. We have Server 2019 DCs, but we're at the 2012 functional level because I have *one stinking Windows XP machine* left I have to support :(

I have this *almost* working, but unfortunately I get a `502` error in Event Viewer:

```
Failed to apply policy and redirect folder "Documents" to "\\fileserver\testuser\".
Redirection options=0x80009210
The following error occurred: "Can't create folder "\\fileserver\testuser"".
Error details: "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.".
```

The thing is... the folder **already exists**, and while the user is indeed not the owner, they do have modification rights. I *do not want* individual users to have rights to create new folders in the root of this share. I do not want to let Folder Redirection create these folders. We are comfortable with our existing user creation scripts. I just want it to use the folder that is already there.

Is this possible, or will I have to make extensive modifications to our account creation scripts, file share structure, and update a few thousand existing shares? (Each of our current folders are their own shared, and not simply a directory in a parent shared folder).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and as described in [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-folder-redirection), you need the user to be the owner.

I understand your concerns about not giving users more permissions, but with the appropiate permissions in the parent folder, you should not worry: I've a share set it up on 2015 as MS recommends, with more than 7000 users now (more than 100 created this month), and it's gave me 0 problems while the time for managing new users has been 0.